# Setting up a Symfony Bundle with unittests against a database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle, pimcore

I am using Pimcore, a framework with Symfony at it's core. Pimcore is programmed by people that do not understand unit testing. They are tightly coupled to the database.

I am writing a bundle to extend the functionalities of Pimcore. However, it goes wrong when the internals of Pimcore try to write to the database:

```
Error: Call to a member function getContainer() on null

/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Pimcore.php:167
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Db.php:49
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/Dao/AbstractDao.php:37
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php:120
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php:54
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/ClassDefinition.php:288
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/Concrete.php:419
/opt/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/Concrete.php:729
/opt/tests/DataObjectTest.php:28
```

The code that actually goes wrong is:

```
/**
 * @return \Pimcore\Db\ConnectionInterface|Connection
 */
public static function get()
{
    /**
     * @var \Pimcore\Db\ConnectionInterface $db
     */
    $db = \Pimcore::getContainer()->get('database_connection');

    return $db;
}
```

I am willing to create the database schema and test against a database for this specific library since mocking away the database is literally impossible. However, I have no idea how to do that since I'm in a standalone bundle that doesn't have the whole config directory in which you define doctrine etc, nor does it have a Kernel.php which even builds the container.

So my question basically is, how can I set up a Kernel Database connection used by PHPUnit?

Comment: Still not clear what you are asking for.  It's easy enough to create your own Doctrine database connection.  Just follow the 'getting started' section in the Doctrine 2 docs.  Also not convinced you can do real unit testing using a database.  Seems more like integration testing.

Comment: It is hard for me to make the question better. Normally you just check out the symfony skeleton and be on your way. But now I just have a /src/ and /test folder. I included symfony in my composer.json, but that's it. There is no App\Kernel, there is no services.yaml. Yet you need that to setup the Kernel and it's containers.

Comment: And why exactly do you need the kernel and it's containers if you are doing unit testings of your own classes?  Are your classes directly dependent on the container?  Seems like you should be able to inject whatever dependencies they need.  Including a database connection.  Which of course you can just create on your own.

Comment: Because the classes I'm dependent upon (Pimcore) do directly depend on them. Not only that, they have made everything final without creating interfaces. Just so you know, I know how unit testing works at a very high level), just trust me when I say it can't be done any other way.

Comment: I have no doubt that you know how testing works.  My simplistic comments were for my benefit.  I really think that @Hast below has the correct approach using the KernelTestCase only you need to create a separate project just for testing.  A hassle to be sure.  Seems like pimcore really perverted Symfony's dependency injection to fit their style.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [KernelTestCase](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/5.4/Test/KernelTestCase.php) class which is a part of [symfony/framework-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle).

Pretty straight manual can be found here: [Testing (Symfony docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html)

Comment: Yes, I am aware how to do this in a normal Symfony project. I just do not know how to do it in a Bundle, where there is no Kernel.

Comment: Then it's just impossible without requiring the whole kernel/doctrine/etc components to your bundle and configuring them before running tests. If I understand it correctly, the main problem happens with the static `get` function which you call inside your bundle and therefore can't be mocked. If so, I see no possibility to create an isolated testing environment for your bundle, without setting up kernel and other components as your bundle's dependencies. Bad Pimcore architecture leaves you no choice.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Bad programming bad. Can you point me in the direction on how to setup a Kernel by yourself? Or do I actually need to checkout the complete skeleton and work from there?

Comment: @David I honestly do not know. I first thought of a solution where you are configuring a whole symfony project in your bundle just for testing, but since your project is a bundle itself, I'm not sure it's possible. Another solution is to create a separate projects with symfony skeleton just for running your bundle's tests. Both approaches are not very satisfying for me though.